# Jquery UI draggable not working after chrome updates

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

```
$('.sceneThumb').draggable({
  drag: function(event, ui) {
  } 
});
```

A simple draggable event like this is not recognised by chrome after chrome updates (current v90). I have tested on chrome v87 and firefox, they all works fine. I have seen posts about removing adBlock extension in chrome, I tried that and no effect too. Anyone can helps me?

Comment: Isn't this something that should be reported to the Chrome team then?

Comment: It seems like it does work on official documentation site https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events. Maybe there is an error in other place? Try to update jQuery libs.

Comment: @Trisma , Hi, thanks for reply. I'll try that.

Comment: @t1m0n , Hi, thanks for reply. I have updated jQuery lib to the latest, no effect. Actually the draggable demo in official documentation is working, i have tried it. It's just that my part of code on draggable isn't working in chrome after v87, but the same piece of code works on firefox. That puzzled me...